# SAPUI5: FileUploader Not Working

Tags: file-upload, odata, sapui5

I am using `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader` for uploading file. I am also adding `slug` and `X-CSRF-Token` with in `header`.But i am unable to send header values to gateway, means in gateway side `csrf token` value is blank.I tested with `Rest Client` its working fine

code:

**View**

```xml
<u:FileUploader
    id="fileUploader1"
    name="myFileUpload"
    mimeType ="image,text"
    uploadUrl=""
    uploadOnChange="false"
    width="400px"
    tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
    uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" />
<Button
    text="Upload File"
    press="handleUploadPress" />
```

**Controller**

```js
handleUploadPress: function (oEvent) {
    var url = "http://xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx:1234/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_GC1_SRV/GCUpload1Set";
    var oFileUploader = this.getView().byId("fileUploader1");
    oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
        name: "slug",
        value: oFileUploader.getValue()
    }));

    oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
        name: "x-csrf-token",
        value: oController.oModel.getSecurityToken()
    }));

    oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
        name: "sendXHR",
        value: true
    }));
    oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(url);
```

Comment: You're setting the header parameter `x-csrf-token` twice. Could it be that the variable `token` is undefined? (You should use the `"use strict"` command to avoid using undeclared variables.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute "sendXHR" has to be set at the FileUploader instance, not as header parameter. Then it should work.

```
oFileUploader.setSendXHR(true);
```